# Reversed loop selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, for-in-loop

I want to see each li of an ul reversed, bottom to top.
I try this but don't work:

```
...
for li in reversed(ol_chat_messages.find_elements_by_xpath(".//li")):
...
```

Comment: please define `don't work`

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested the code but I think `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a generator.

Hence you have to convert it to a list to be used by reversed, like this:

```
for li in reversed(list(ol_chat_messages.find_elements_by_xpath(".//li"))):
```

Sample verifying code:

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <ul>
...     <li>1</li>
...     <li>2</li>
...     <li>3</li>
...     <li>4</li>
...     <li>5</li>
... </ul>'''
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> open('temp.htm', 'w').write(HTML)
70
>>> driver.get('file://c:/scratch/temp.htm')
>>> for li in reversed(list(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li'))):
...     li.text
...     
'5'
'4'
'3'
'2'
'1'
```